# Mysql not starting automatically

Tags: startup, automatic

I'd like mysql to start on boot but it does not.

Now in order to run it I need to run:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Each time that I power on my computer, which is annoying.

How to resolve this?

a)
This did not help

```
 sudo update-rc.d mysql remove
 sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

b)
It did not help to change

```
bind-address= 0.0.0.0
```

in mysql.cnf

c) It did not help to copy a new mysql file from this thread
[mysql does not start automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582359/mysql-does-not-start-automatically)

None of the solutions helped. mysql does not start after boot.
But it works fine when starting by hand.

Comment: did you check file /var/log/syslog for mysql messages?

Comment: see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/582359/mysql-does-not-start-automatically?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.

Comment: Kuntal - I posted this link myself - see c)

Comment: Aug  9 17:22:35 /etc/mysql/debian-start[878]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Aug  9 17:22:35 1 /etc/mysql/debian-start[882]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Aug  9 17:22:35 /etc/mysql/debian-start[882]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Aug  9 17:22:35  /etc/mysql/debian-start[882]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Aug  9 17:22:35 /etc/mysql/debian-start[882]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.49, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade